# $L_{\infty}$ norm of Fejer Integral

Tags: functional-analysis

How does one show the following?

$||\sigma_n(f)||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_{\infty}$, where

$\sigma_n(f)(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+t)K_n(t)\, dt$, and 
$K_n(t) = \frac{\sin^2(nt/2)}{2n\sin^2(t/2)}$.

I've shown this to be true for the $L_2$-norm, however I am not sure how to extend the result for $L_{\infty}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You know that $1/{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi K_n(t)dt=1$. Now just apply Hölder's inequality with exponents $1$ and $\infty$.

Comment: The fact that $K_n$ is non-negativer is also important.